# WPF button's common style for "Enable" and "Disable" states

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, exception, button

I try to make WPF button's common style for either it is enabled or disabled:

```
    <Style x:Name="btnStyle" x:Key="btnStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground"  Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFCFFFFF"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Style" Value="{DynamicResource btnStyle}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Style" Value="{DynamicResource btnStyle}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

and my button:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource btnStyle}"/>
```

This generates following exception on running.

```
"Style object is not allowed to affect the Style property of the object to which it applies."
```

How can I apply this common style to my button's both states? And can I do it without overriding button's template only with styles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution with the help of @adminSoftDK's answer. I set the same styles on both of the trigger properties.

```
<Style x:Key="btnStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground"  Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFCFFFFF"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground"  Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFCFFFFF"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 6):

Your btnStyle is a style, and all the properties you want to change while enabled or disabled go inside the trigger, for example

```
 <Style x:Name="btnStyle" x:Key="btnStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground"  Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFCFFFFF"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="Enabled" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="Disabled" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: I don't want to change the style. I just want it to be same either state is changing or not.